# What is the Javadoc specification for in an Eclipse user library entry?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I've created a user library in Eclipse containing one object code JAR and specifying a Javadoc JAR and a source code JAR.

I've found the source code archive is necessary and sufficient to let the Java editor display my Javadoc when code completion is used with the members I've documented.

Given that the source code archive is necessary and sufficient, what I'd like to know is: what's the purpose of adding the Javadoc JAR to the library entry?

I'd like to be able to explain it to others.

Comment: Not all source code contains Javadoc, or you might not have source code at all.\

Comment: If that be true, then I should be able to get the context sensitive help in the Java editor having associated only the Javadoc with the JAR while not associating the source code. But it doesn't seem to happen.